# sem_post() fails with errno = bad file descriptor in iOS

Tags: ios, synchronization, semaphore

I am trying the following code:

```
if (sem_post(sem) == -1)
{
    printf("syncr_release error %d\n", errno);
    perror("Error:");
    return ERROR;
}
```

and it's giving the following output:

```
syncr_release error 9
Error:: Bad file descriptor
```

I cannot find anything about that error code in the documentation about sem_post(). How can I solve this?